Is there a database of oligonucleotide duplex sequences and their melting temperatures
I am looking for melting temperatures of oligonucleotide duplexes, but I am having trouble finding data. Can be DNA-DNA, DNA-RNA, or RNA-RNA duplexes, native or modified nucleotides.

DNA-DNA you can easily find in many website if you do some google search. I can tell you relative stability of these duplexes. RNA-RNA > DNA-RNA > DNA-DNA.

Not exactly what you're asking, but the modeling program/API ViennaRNA has excellent and accurate utilities for predicting the stability ($\Delta \Delta G$ of folding) for arbitrary oligonucleotide RNA/DNA sequences.
Failing that, as mentioned in the comments, there are many studies with some restricted datasets (such as this one, see Table S4, and this one. See also references therein).
I am having trouble finding an actual database as most hybridization studies seem to have been performed before data deposition was standard practice, and my inference is that people tend to trust the models at this point. See for example this evaluation of the nearest-neighbor model for duplex formation.

I confer this answer. ViennaRNA has a massive bank of programs for this exact task and predicts thermodynamic stability in each. They are highly reputable, choosing the appropriate program can be a bit tricky, there's a lot of them.
